# Android edittext with Hebrew (Right-to-Left) text right align

Tags: android, android-edittext, right-to-left

I have an edittext.
From the code I set it with hebrew text, however the text is left align (to the left border of the edittext)

Here it the part from the XML file:

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="240dip" 
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:lines="7"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/field" 
    android:id="@+id/userEditTextId"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:hint="כתוב פה..." />
```

Comment: Still an issue - even on Android 4.3 (SGS4)

Answer (score 0):

yeh, people are still asking that question until recently
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/971bd9df400ca89e